# uitableview in ios 7 scrolls above status bar

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a UITableView having custom UITableViewCell. it has UITextField. in order to avoid hiding of UITextField below the keyboard, i wrote a custom method to move up the View when text field is under keyboard.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
if (up) {
    if (frame.origin.y >= 0) {
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 120;
    }
} else {
    if (frame.origin.y >= -150) {
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 120;
    }

}
[self.view setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

this works fine and the table view is going up and down according to my requirements in ios 6.

But in ios 7 when the view is up, the tableview is shown above status bar. As an alternate i tried setting content inset for tableview and scrolling to row at position. But it was not up to my requirement. Please suggest a method to hide tableview above status bar.

Comment: check


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509830/adds-bar-showing-up-form-bottom-in-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

So I pretty much assume you are using previous iOS 6 style status bar. In iOS 6 when you move your view upward, it takes care of status bar and view does not come over status bar. But in iOS 7 although you show status bar in iOS 6 style, you can't let your views go under status bar when you move you view upward.

[See this post for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style)

and also have a look at [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

try in your viewcontroller in viewDidLoad:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on iOS 8 when set on my UITableView `clipsToBounds = NO`
Setting back to `YES` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

ios 7 has +20 Pixles than ios 6.

check

[Adds Bar showing up form Bottom in ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509830/adds-bar-showing-up-form-bottom-in-ios-7)